# Minimum & Maximum Logic

Tags: c#, wpf

I have problem using a WPF zoomable canvas library, the library works smoothly, however no matter what I try I can't set the minimum or maximum to the scaling (Zooming), it scales (zoomes) in or out as much as possible without any limits, how can I set the limits? for example the zoom shouldn't be less than 1 and more than 5.

This is the code I use below:

```
    void PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = Math.Pow(2, e.Delta / 3.0 / System.Windows.Input.Mouse.MouseWheelDeltaForOneLine);
        MyCanvas.Scale *= x;
        // Adjust the offset to make the point under the mouse stay still.
        var position = (System.Windows.Vector)e.GetPosition(basecan);
        MyCanvas.Offset = (System.Windows.Point)((System.Windows.Vector)
            (MyCanvas.Offset + position) * x - position);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I have spent hours trying to get it to work, thanks for your help.

[Here is the library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/18/zoomableapplication3-when-not-to-applytransform.aspx)

Comment: Clamp `MyCanvas.Scale` to your range.

Comment: @clcto, can you elaborate please?

Comment: `MyCanvas.Scale = Math.Max( 1, Math.Min( MyCanvas.Scale * x, 5 ) );`

Comment: @clcto, thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just clip the scale to the limits?

```
class XXX{
    double scale = 1;
    public void PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e){
        this.scale *= Math.Pow(2, e.Delta / 3.0 / System.Windows.Input.Mouse.MouseWheelDeltaForOneLine);
        if (this.scale > 5) this.scale = 5;
        else if (this.scale < 1) this.scale = 1;
        MyCanvas.Scale = this.scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that already, for some reason it doesn't stop it, and it jitters.

Comment: If it jitters that means there may be some other thread modifying it. Try creating a new global variable to store the scale. See my modified answer.

Comment: That seems to be working for setting the zoom limit, however it messes up the adjusting the offset, which doesn't stay where it should be, sorry for being a noob.

Comment: Well that is good to hear, you have solved at least half of the problem. I'm currently guessing how the offset is calculated, but try `MyCanvas.Offset*= Math.Pow(............)`

Comment: Note: you need to recalculate that based on the ratio between the old scale and the new scale. They should be inside the "if" statements as well.

Comment: Cannot set the offset like that as the offset is a Point, however even after creating a Point with the Math method, still doesn't work, anyhow that is what I get for not writing my own libraries, thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Well offset is a Point, but you can consider it as a 2D-vector. So `p.X*=2; p.Y*=2;` . It's just figuring out the math for that point. That can't be hard.